# Will Appharbor wipe the stored avatars when deploying a new build

Tags: appharbor

I am new to appharbor and want to make sure before this comes up later.  When deploying, does it wipe the directories clean and then deploy? I store the users avatars on disk within the images/avatars folder.  I want to ensure this doesn't get wiped, if it does, is there a special directory I can use or a setting to tell appharbor not to wipe this directory?

Answer (score 1):

You cannot use the AppHarbor worker instance filesystems for permanent storage. They're not persisted. We recommend you use AWS S3 instead. There's more info in the [FAQ](http://support.appharbor.com/kb/getting-started/frequently-asked-questions).